# WPF DataTemplate doesn't match DataType when high CPU load

Tags: wpf, xaml, treeview, datatemplate, hierarchicaldatatemplate

Here is my code

```
<TreeView x:Name="MyTreeView" ItemsSource="{Binding MyDataList}" Grid.Row="0" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
<TreeView.Resources>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ParentDataType}" ItemsSource="{Binding ChildsList}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            <TextBlock Text=" [" Foreground="Blue"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ChildsList.Count}" Foreground="Blue"/>
            <TextBlock Text="]" Foreground="Blue"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ChildDataType}">
        <uc:UCScheduleView DataContext="{Binding}" Visibility="{Binding IsResultLoad, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource BoolVisibilityConverter}}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</TreeView.Resources>
<TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </Style>
</TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

As you can see, I have a `TreeView` and use `HierarchicalDataTemplate` and `DataTemplate` to display my data.

This XAML-code works fine. As a result, I get a tree with first-level elements of type `ParentDataType` and second-level elements of type `ChildDataType`.

But when there is a high CPU loading, the `HierarchicalDataTemplate` stops matching `DataType` and I get "MyModule.ViewModel.ParentDataType" (this is the result of `ToString()` on the `ParentDataType` instance) in my `TreeView` on the first level of the tree.

But this is not all. The problem occurs randomly. After the application started the tree is empty. I can add first element of type `ParentDataType` from the database to `MyDataList` and the first-level element is added to the tree. So, if that first loading is success, than the loading of all other data from database doesn't lead to the problem, everything will be OK. But if the problem occurs while first loading from database, than the loading of all other data from database doesn't lead to the problem too. So, the problem may occur only while loading first data item from the database and doesn't occurs later until I restart the application.

So, I described the case when the problem occurs. As mentioned in title of the question, the problem occurs only when there is a high CPU loading. I simulating CPU loading as described [here](https://superuser.com/a/396524) and the problem occurs when ~75% CPU loading.

It looks like the high CPU usage interferes with WPF, so WPF skips the data types comparision while DataTemplate applying and performs `ToString()` despite the presence of DataType attribute ...

Answer (score 0):

You should use Virtualization. Maybe WPF just stops rendering the template and only shows the string representation.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716879

Comment: Virtualization is used when there is large amount of data, isn't it? My data list I bound to the TreeView is initially empty. The problem occurs when I add first element to the data list.

Comment: Could you post a full working sample? I couldn't reproduce.

Comment: I can't unfortunally. This is very large app with database connection.

Comment: Just a minimal working example to reproduce the issue. With some mocking data.

Comment: Sorry, I can't do that. But thank you for participating.